# Firebase cant successfully get to my Users Table in my android app

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

After hours of figuring out how to integrate Firebase with my app I have finally managed to do so. Now, I have created a Users table (if I followed Google's documentation right) and added fields for my first user

[image]

Also, I set my rules as such:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

This is how I have my sign in fragment:

```
public class SignInFragment extends Fragment {

    public static SignInFragment newInstance()
    {
        return new SignInFragment();
    }

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login,
                container, false);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        final Button btnSignIn = view.findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);
        final EditText email = view.findViewById(R.id.email_text);
        final EditText password = view.findViewById(R.id.password_Text);

        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                GetUser(email.toString(), password.toString());
            }
        });    
        return view;
    }

    private void  GetUser(String email, String password) {
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"User found!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"No user by that email!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

}
```

When I get to my sign in screen and enter the same email and password that I have in my Users table it shows me the "incorrect user" toast message. I have checked my entries and everything matches. So my question is: what am I doing wrong? Am I missing more steps to get to my Users table? It is also worth noting that my code is entirely predicated on the Firebase Assistant, under the Authentication tutorial in Android Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `email.toString()` use `email.getText().toString()`

Comment: yay it worked! Thank you so much. I also found out that I had to go to my Firebase console and enable email authentication.